# Citrix Receiver URL?

Tags: url, citrix, citrix-receiver

Is it possible to craft a hyperlink that when clicked will cause Citrix Receiver to open an appilcation with the given arguments? For example, I have Citrix Receiver on my computer with an Internet Explorer application. I would like to make a link like:

citrix://Internet%20Explorer%20http%3A%2F%2Fsite-that-only-works-in-ie.com

In order to open http://site-that-only-works-in-ie.com using Internet Explorer. Is this possible, or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a resource shortcut for the IE application. While publishing the same application in studio you can mention the website URL you want to open in IE.

https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/storefront/2-6/dws-manage/dws-configure-site.html